# Elasticsearch Java API query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder

I`m newbie with elasticsearch querybuilder, Could someone give a constructed query for this below one in Java API

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/mone/mone/_search?pretty=true" -d'
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "ABC",
                "fields": ["Data.Type"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": { "Data.Date": "01.06.2014" }
        }
    }
   }
}'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "give me the code" question.

Comment: Sorry. I worked it out by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FilterQueryBuilder I got it to work

```
FilteredQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("Spectra"), FilterBuilders.termFilter("Data.Date", "01.06.2014"));


        SearchResponse response = elasticClient.prepareSearch("mone")
                .setTypes("mone")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setQuery(builder)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        System.out.println(response);
```

Hope this answer will be useful to some newbies like me.

Comment: Usage of DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH is strongly discouraged. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/relevance-is-broken.html